# Map a List of Objects with @OneToMany to a PostgreSQL array column

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have an entity `Person` which has a `@OneToMany` annotated `List<Address> addresses` property.

`Address` has an `UUID` property annotated with `UserType` as primary key.

I would like to map the list of addresses to a `PostgreSQL` array column `uuid[]`, instead of having either a mapping table or a reference in the address table.

Is this possible ?